# Is spark 1.6.3 compatible with Kafka 1.0.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have spark 1.6.3, Scala 2.10.5 and Kafka 1.0.0, is it possible to use Kafka 1.0.0 with Scala 2.10.5?

Answer (score 1):

No. Kafka 1.0.0 requires Scala 2.11 or 2.12.

https://kafka.apache.org/downloads#1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Spark-Streaming v1.6.3 clients can communicate with Kafka 1.0 brokers, yes.

I'm not sure how you got an old version of Scala because the Spark 1.6.3 downloads are built for Scala 2.11